# How to show a greeting message through out the day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to show a greeting message through out the day. If it's 12 am through 11:59 am i want a good morning message and so on. This is what i have but cant seem to get it working.

```
def greet
    if Time.now <= Time.now.beginning_of_day
        render :text =>"Good Morning"
    elsif Time.now <= Time.now.middle_of_day
        render :text => "Good Afternoon"
    elsif Time.now <= Time.now.change(:hour => 5 )
        render :text => "Good Evening"
    elsif Time.now <= Time.now.change(:hour => 8 )
        render :text =>"Good Night"
    end
end
```

I will be displaying something like this in my views.

```
<# This should display a greeting to the user %>
<%= greet %> <%= current_user.name %>
```

Comment: What does "can't seem to get it working" mean, exactly? What view is supposed to be displaying your greeting?

Comment: you can use Time.now.hour

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, let's make the time a bit easier to read. I set the five variables below based on your conditions. I also convert these to epoch time via `to_i`

```
  current_time = Time.now.to_i
  midnight = Time.now.beginning_of_day.to_i
  noon = Time.now.middle_of_day.to_i
  five_pm = Time.now.change(:hour => 17 ).to_i
  eight_pm = Time.now.change(:hour => 20 ).to_i
```

You can then use your `if` conditions to display the correct text (or render as you had it).

```
  if midnight.upto(noon).include?(current_time)
    puts "Good Morning"
  elsif noon.upto(five_pm).include?(current_time)
    puts  "Good Afternoon"
  elsif five_pm.upto(eight_pm).include?(current_time)
    puts "Good Evening"
  elsif eight_pm.upto(midnight + 1.day).include?(current_time)
    puts "Good Night"
  end
```

Or, you can move away from `if` statements and use `case`.

```
  case 
   when midnight.upto(noon).include?(current_time)
    puts "Good Morning"
   when noon.upto(five_pm).include?(current_time)
    puts  "Good Afternoon"
   when five_pm.upto(eight_pm).include?(current_time)
    puts "Good Evening"
   when eight_pm.upto(midnight + 1.day).include?(current_time)
    puts "Good Night"
  end
```

Personally, what you had works, but you're not creating true definitions of the boundaries. While this may not be a big deal, I do like having definitive boundaries set just in case something happens down the road which could cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

Giving my 20 cents:

```
  def greet
    case Time.zone.now.hour
    when 4..11 then 'Bom dia'
    when 12..17 then 'Boa tarde'
    when 18..23 then 'Boa noite'
    else
      'Olá'
    end
  end
```

There is also an option with hash (IMO it is ugly):

```
{
  0..11 => 'Good Morning', 
  12..17 => 'Good Afternoon', 
  18..23 => 'Good Night'
}.find { |k, v| break v if k.cover? Time.zone.now.hour }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
now = Time.now
today = Date.today.to_time

morning = today.beginning_of_day
noon = today.noon
5pm = today.change( hour: 17 )
8pm = today.change( hour: 20 )
tomorrow = today.tomorrow

message = case now
when morning..noon
  'Good Morning'
when noon..5pm
  'Good Afternoon'
when 5pm..8pm
  'Good Evening'
when 8pm..tomorrow
  'Good Night'
end

render text: message
```

I don't think `Time.now` will ever be less than `Time.now.beginning_of_day`

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly @daslicious answer gave `can't iterate from Time` error. So I modified it to use the `if-else` conditionals.

```
def greet
  now = Time.now
  today = Date.today.to_time

  morning = today.beginning_of_day
  noon = today.noon
  evening = today.change( hour: 17 )
  night = today.change( hour: 20 )
  tomorrow = today.tomorrow

  if (morning..noon).cover? now
    'Good Morning'
  elsif (noon..evening).cover? now
    'Good Afternoon'
  elsif (evening..night).cover? now
    'Good Evening'
  elsif (night..tomorrow).cover? now
    'Good Night'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `between?` method from `Comparable` module.

```
def greet
  if Time.now.between? Time.now.beginning_of_day, Time.now.middle_of_day
    render :text =>"Good Morning"
  elsif Time.now.between? Time.now.middle_of_day, Time.now.change(hour: 17)
    render :text => "Good Afternoon"
  elsif Time.now.between? Time.now.change(hour: 17), Time.now.change(hour: 20)
    render :text => "Good Evening"
  elsif Time.now.between? Time.now.change(hour: 20), Time.now.end_of_day
    render :text =>"Good Night"
  end
end
```